# WAMP: MySQL not running with network drive

Tags: mysql, wamp, network-drive

I have copies of WAMP running on some computers. All copies of WAMP use the same database. So far, this database was in the WAMP-installation on each of the computers and I had to synchronize these databases manually by exporting and importing dump files.

Now I started using an external hard drive on which I made a copy of the database files. When I connect this external hard drive to any of the computers and replace in the file my.ini  the path to the database by setting

```
datadir="G:/mysql/mysql5.7.9/data"
```

where G is the drive letter of the external hard drive, everything works fine.

However, when I attach the external hard drive to the usb port of my router and make it available on any of my computers with the drive letter Z, and when I adapt the file my.ini by setting

```
 datadir="Z:/mysql/mysql5.7.9/data",
```

WAMPSERVER does not start up the mysql service and when I try to open phpMyAdmin, it fails with the message that it cannot connect to the MySQL-server.

I would be very grateful if someone can give me some idea why WAMPSERVER does not start up correctly with the network drive and how to overcome this problem.

Comment: So what errors are you seeing in the MySQL Error log? Or if that is no help the Windows Event Viewer

Comment: @RiggsFolly. Many thanks for your reaction. The sort of errors I saw where of the type 'could not connect'. After studying another lot of posts in this and other forums, I think that the explanation is that for some or other reason MySQL and PHP cannot work with drive letters assigned to network drives by Windows. When in the code I replace the drive letter Z with //192.168.0.1/volume9, which is my assignment to Z, everything works fine.

Comment: That is correct. It is always best to use a UNC address [see](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/platform/windows.html)